# Python import not found after VSCode restart

Tags: python, directory, python-import, pylance

My Python import could not be found after i changed the directory and restarted VSCode.

I installed the package via cmd (pip install ) and it was found in Vscode.
I restarted VSCode because i changed the file location to a other directory. The package wasnt found since then. I uninstalled the package and installed it via Powershell but it wouldnt work. Updated the pip installer.
Created a new file with in the directory where it has been before and installed the package again.
VSCode doesnt recognize the package anymore.
Import "" could not be Resolved (Pylance(reportMissingImports))
Does anybody know why this behavious appears and how to fix it?
I havent found a proper solution on here or another forum

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom right of your VS code instance, you'll see something like `3.11.0 64-bit`, which indicates the version of Python that VS code is referring to when running and linting your code. The problem is you installed the package with a different version of Python. If you click on the aforementioned button (that says `3.11.0 64-bit`) you should see a list of options show up for the different Python versions installed. You need to change to the one that you installed the package on.